# Inserting data on VarBinary(max) column on SQL Server does not insert full length VarBinary

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've got the following SQL code (the varbinary has around 90k characters):

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_TABLE (NAME, VERSION, OBJECT) 
                     VALUES (@P1, @P2, @P3)',
                   N'@P1 varchar(8000),@P2 varchar(8000),@P3 varbinary(max)',
                   'TEST', '1.0', 0x3C3F786D6C2076657273696F6E3D22312E302220656E63.......
```

After I execute this code, if I do:

```
SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE
```

the results I get in the `OBJECT` column are only half of the characters that I inserted (about 45k characters).

I also tried the following:

```
DECLARE @EXAMPLE AS VARBINARY(MAX)
SET @EXAMPLE = CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), <my varbinary>, 1)

EXEC sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_TABLE (NAME, VERSION, OBJECT) VALUES (@P1, @P2, @P3)',
                   N'@P1 varchar(8000),@P2 varchar(8000),@P3 varbinary(max)',
                   'TEST','1.0', @EXAMPLE
```

And the exact same thing happens.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you determining that the value is truncated? SSMS will not tell you if you are `SELECT`ing and copying the value, as the maximum length you can return at most 65535 characters, which is less than 90K.

Comment: I [can't replicate](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=73d07f6e648f2bf926166b859b5d056b) your problem. Can you supply an [mre]?

Comment: not sure about the truncate state. I posted the varbinary that i'm using in the following link:
https://pastebin.com/Z1t9GrUZ

Comment: I still [can't replicate](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=68935736dff13a3d7d38c4cef62bdb33) your problem, Raphael. You need to supply an [mre].

Answer (score 1):

I think you're understanding what binary literals are. Binary literals are `0x` plus 2 hexadecimal characters encoding each byte of data.

In your question the binary literal is 89380 characters long which is:

- 2 characters for the `0x`, plus
- 89378 characters for the hexadecimal characters

This encodes 44689 bytes of data, i.e.: `89378 / 2 = 44689`.

If you `select datalength(object) from example_table` for your question's example you get 44689 which is the correct length.